# Unable to receive full response from web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

I Write the code for getting the json data from service by posting the parameters,but I am not getting the full response from webservice,like i want  display 500 timed questions,but it display only 20 questions,when check the services in advanced rest client then webservices give the full reponse,but through the android program iam not getting full response, my code :-

```
public static String postRequest(Context ct, String url,
            List<NameValuePair> postvalues) throws IllegalStateException,
            IOException
{
    mContext = ct;
    HttpPost post = null;
    String content = null;

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 1000 *1;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeoutConnection);


    int timeoutSocket = 60 * 1000 *30;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeoutSocket);

    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    String srvURL = mainurl + url;

    // Log.i("Webservise", "url="+srvURL);
    post = new HttpPost(srvURL);
    post.setHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postvalues, HTTP.UTF_8));

    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 32);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            // Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.e("Webservice call", "Response kp=" + json.toString());

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(ct, "Request time out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do something for all other types of exception.
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return json;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Instead of using BufferedReader I converted the response to string using EntityUtil.
Try this

```
try{
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

   json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```